# DataTable is not a function on Windows

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have problem with DataTables. I have simple code which is running on Mac/Linux BUT doesn't work on Windows... This is very strange, I have no idea why it is happening. Did anyone have similar problem?
Here is the sample code:
https://codepen.io/poncki/pen/PoQmOKe

On my machine with Windows 10 and any browser below errors occur:

```
jquery.dataTables.js:15301 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at jquery.dataTables.js:15301:22
at jquery.dataTables.js:55:22
at jquery.dataTables.js:58:1

jquery-3.6.0.js:4059 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):229:36)
at mightThrow (jquery-3.6.0.js:3766:29)
at process (jquery-3.6.0.js:3834:12)
```

I have proper configuration (first is loaded jQuery and then DataTables lib). With the older version of DataTables (1.10.13) it is working fine, but I have to use 1.12.0. Any help?

Comment: The codepen works for me.

Comment: The OS will have no bearing on the outcome. That's a coincidence. More likely the issue is due to the browser, or caching on each machine.

Comment: Unless you can provide a [mre] it may be difficult to help you. We can only make educated guesses.